# Homotopy fibre of pushout

Tags: homotopy-theory, covering-spaces, fiber-bundles

Let $(f_U,f_A,f_V):(U\leftarrow A\rightarrow V)\to (U'\leftarrow A'\rightarrow V')$ be a morphism of diagrams of topological spaces and let $f:U\sqcup_A V\to U'\sqcup_{A'} V'$ be the resulting morphisms for the pushouts.

Suppose I know the (weak) homotopy type of the homotopy fibres of $f_U$, $f_A$ and $f_V$. Is there any chance to say something about the homotopy fibre of $f$?

To be more precise: In my special situation, I know that $f_U$, $f_A$ and $f_V$ are all coverings and I would be happy if I could conclude that $\pi_2(\mathrm{hofib}(f))=0$.

Comment: I can't think of anything direct, unless you have more information available about the diagram map. I think your best bet will be to study the cofibers of the map. In this case $C_f$ is the homotopy pushout of $(C_{f_U}\leftarrow C_{f_A}\rightarrow C_{f_V})$, and you may be able to get a good grasp of its cohomology. Then use this to show that $f$ is sufficiently connected so as to be able to conclude that $\pi_2F_f=0$.

Comment: I doubt it. Consider $U'=A'=V' = \{*\}$ (singleton) and $U = V$ disks, glued along $A = S^1$. Then the homotopy fiber of $f$ is $S^2$. These are not covering maps, but they are fibrations...